# Kotlin BLE scan issue with Huawei

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, huawei-mobile-services

I'm developing an App using BLE and I need to be able to connect to Android and iOS devices.

I have 3 Samsung Devices, 3 iPhones and one Huawei with Android for testing purposes.

I have an issue with the Huawei device..when scanning for advertisements, Huawei finds all Android devices but no iOS ones. But if I turn bluetooth off and on again, it will find the iOS devices this time if I scan. But only the first time, it won't find them again afterwards until I turn bluetooth off/on again.

Again..only the Huawei is having these issues..what can be the cause?

I scan/advertise like this:

```
val settings = AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
            .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED)
            .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_MEDIUM)
            .setConnectable(true)
            .build()

        val pUuid = ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString(BluetoothStringsValues.SERVICE_UUID))

        val data = AdvertiseData.Builder()
            .setIncludeDeviceName(false)
            .addServiceUuid(pUuid)
            .addServiceData(pUuid, stringToAdvertise.toByteArray(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
            .build()
        advertiser.startAdvertising(settings, data, advertisingCallback)

val filter = ScanFilter.Builder()
        .setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString(SERVICE_UUID)))
        .build()
    val settings = ScanSettings.Builder()
        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED)
        .build()

    bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(listOf(filter), settings, bleScanCallback)
```

thanks for the help!